# tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() returns None

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on using multi-GPU tower defs on my work, but it seems to have errors: too big losses and not updated.

I think the problems are come from the code below:

```
# Calculate the gradients for each model tower.
tower_grads = []
for i in xrange(num_gpus):
  with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
    with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
      loss = tower_loss(scope)

      ####### HERE #######
      # Reuse variables for the next tower.
      tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
      ####################

      grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
      tower_grads.append(grads)
```

`print(tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables())` prints `None`.

What's the problem do you think?

I set the variable_scope only with CONV1, CONV2, FC3, FC4 in INFERENCE just like in `cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem in your code, at least not with `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()`.

The function `reuse_variables()` will always produce `None` as a result. Its only function is to set the attribute `reuse` of the current scope to `True`.

I think you mistake it with a function that would return all the variables in the current scope.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you are looking for `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse`.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L868), as you can see it has no return. Thus what you can get and print out is just None. Here is the relevant snippet:

```
  def reuse_variables(self):
    """Reuse variables in this scope."""
    self._reuse = True
```

Actually, it just switches the _reuse on.